# In gradient descent for collaborative filtering, are x and theta update simultaneous?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I'm taking Andrew Ng's machine learning course and I'm on chapter 16: Recommender Systems. I currently finished watching the part about collaborative filtering.
In it, he talked about how you can guess the parameters: theta, then use it to predict x and use the predicted x to learn better parameters, and so on.
He also said it could be done simultaneously and gave the gradient descent algorithm for it:

[image: Image of gradient descent algorithm for collaborative filtering]

I want to ask if x and theta are updated simultaneously. E.g,
for each iteration: after performing a single gradient descent on x, do i recalculate the square error sum using the new values of x and then perform a gradient descent on theta then repeat until convergence.
OR
do i perform a single gradient descent on x, using the same squared error sum, perform a gradient descent on theta too

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one update simultaneously. You could even summarize it in one formular updating `x` and theta at the same time using:
[image]